# Cannot access offset of type string on string while trying to access an array in an object in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, api

i am a bit confused as i have tried what i understand about fetching an item in an array in an object .

let me break down

in my client endpoint

```
 $client=Client::where('id',$client)->firstOrFail();

 $arr = json_decode($client->attributes);

 return response()->json($arr);
```

when i return like this

```
return response()->json($client->attributes);
```

i get

```
{
    "full_details_acknowledgement": "10",
    "offer_letter_acknowledgement": "10",
    "offer_letter": "10",
    "offer_letter_variables": [
        "basic_salary",
        "housing_allowance",
        "transport_allowance",
        "meal",
        "entertainment",
        "hazard_allowance",
        "leave_allowance",
        "utility",
        "monthly_gross_salary",
        "statutory_deductions",
        "employee_pension",
        "payee_tax",
        "total_deductions",
        "net_monthly_salary",
        "austin"
    ],
    "company": "global-manpower"
}
```

i am trying to get the values of offer_letter_variables and safe them in a variable

like this , this is also what i have tried

```
foreach ($client->attributes['offer_letters_variables'] as $variable){
           
            $offer_letters_variables->put($variable,isset($request->{$variable}) ? $request->{$variable} : 0 );

        }
```

but if i try it as the above i have the error

`"message": "Cannot access offset of type string on string"`

heres a full view of my code(i commented out some parts)

```
 public function submitSingleUploadCandidates($client,Request $request){
       
        $request->validate([
            'job_role_id'=>'required',
            'mail_template_id'=>'required',
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'user_type'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
        ]);
        
        $job_level=JobLevel::find($request->job_level_id);

        $job_role=JobRole::findOrFail($request->job_role_id);

        $mail_template=MailTemplate::findOrFail($request->mail_template_id);

        $client=Client::where('id',$client)->firstOrFail();

        //return response()->json($client->attributes);

        // $arr = json_decode($client->attributes);

        //dd($client);
        // return response()->json(gettype($arr));
        // return response()->json($arr);

        $offer_letters_variables=collect([]);
        
      //return response()->json($offer_letters_variables);
        
        // $var = $client->attributes[''];
        
        // dd($var);
        
        
        foreach ($client->attributes['offer_letters_variables'] as $variable){
           
            $offer_letters_variables->put($variable,isset($request->{$variable}) ? $request->{$variable} : 0 );

        }

        $attr=collect(['offer_letter_variables'=>$offer_letters_variables]);

        $user=User::where('email',$request->email)->first();

        
        
        if ($user){
            Session::flash('fail', 'Candidate with email already exist');
            $payload=['status'=>'fail','details'=>'Candidate with email already exist'];
            return response()->json($payload, 200);
            return  redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }
            $password=Str::random(7);

            $job_level_id = $job_level->id ?? null;

            $new_user=User::create([
                'client_id'=>$client->id,
                'email'=>$request->email,
                'emp_num'=>$request->emp_num,
                'first_name'=>$request->first_name,
                'last_name'=>$request->last_name,
                'stage_id'=>1,
                'user_type'=>$request->user_type,
                'job_level_id'=>$job_level_id,
                'job_role_id'=>$job_role->id,
                'attributes'=>$attr,
                'password'=>Hash::make($password),
            ]);

            // $mail_constants['MacTay Signature Banner'] = '';

            $mail_constants = $this->getMailConstants($new_user);
            $mail_constants['candidate_password']=$password;
            $mail_constants['deadline']=Carbon::now()->addWeekdays(2)->format('D d M, Y');
            $mail_constants['admin_name']=auth()->user()->name;
            $mail_content=$this->convertMailTemplateToEmail($mail_template,$mail_constants);

            $mail_template->subject = str_replace('{{job_role}}', $mail_constants['job_role'], $mail_template->subject);
            $mail_template->subject = str_replace('{{client_name}}', $mail_constants['client_name'], $mail_template->subject);

            Mail::to($new_user->email)->send(new AdminSendMail($mail_content,$mail_template->subject));
            $message="Your account has been created on Mactay App. Email: {$new_user->email}, Temp Password: {$password}. URL: onboarding.mactay.com";

            SendSMSJob::dispatch($new_user->phone,$message);

            activity()->withProperties(['client_id' => $client->id])->log('Upload single candidate to '.$client->name);
            Session::flash('success', 'Successfully Uploaded Single Candidates Details');
          
            $payload=['status'=>'success','details'=>'Successfully Uploaded Single Candidates Details'];
            return response()->json($payload, 200);

    }
```

please what am i doing wrong, please help , thanks in advance

Comment: you want `offer_letter_variables` from db collection right?

Comment: yes i do @sohailamar

Comment: You don't (indeed, shouldn't) provide all the code, but a [**minimal**, **complete** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It doesn't (indeed, shouldn't) even need to call external APIs, unless your question is about calling the API (which this question isn't). See also "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: There's a difference between a complaint and constructive criticism. Note the linked page is SO's official policy, and exists to help you to ask a quality question and get quality answers. Please read the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @outis thank you, so now do you have a possible solution?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to json_decode `$client->attributes`

```
$clientAttributes = json_decode($client->attributes);

foreach ($clientAttributes->offer_letter_variables as $variable){
  $offer_letters_variables->put(
    $variable,
    $request->{$variable} ?? 'not set'
  );
}

$attr = collect(['offer_letter_variables' => $offer_letters_variables]);
```

if you want to access it like an array you can json_decode the value like as an associative array.

```
$clientAttributes = json_decode($client->attributes, true);

dd($clientAttributes['offer_letter_variables']);
```

Also not that you have misspelled `offer_letter_variables` as `offer_letters_variables` in you foreach loop.

Comment: thank you @maazin you just solved the issue, this `$clientAttributes = json_decode($client->attributes, true);

dd($clientAttributes['offer_letter_variables']);` give me what i need and i use it as i want

Answer (score 0):

You will get `offer_letter_variables` like this.

```
$offerLetters = 0;
$client=Client::where('id',$client)->firstOrFail();
if(isset($client->attributes['offer_letter_variables'])){
   $offerLetters = $client->attributes['offer_letter_variables'];
}
```

Comment: same error `"message": "Cannot access offset of type string on string",
    "exception": "TypeError",`

Comment: please dump the `$client->attributes` output

Comment: here you go `"{"full_details_acknowledgement":"10","offer_letter_acknowledgement":"10","offer_letter":"10","offer_letter_variables":["basic_salary","housing_allowance","transport_allowance","meal","entertainment","hazard_allowance","leave_allowance","utility","monthly_gross_salary","statutory_deductions","employee_pension","payee_tax","total_deductions","net_monthly_salary","austin"],"company":"global-manpower"}"`

Comment: `$offerLetters = $client->attributes->offer_letter_variables;` please try this

Comment: heres the result `"message": "Attempt to read property \"offer_letter_variables\" on string",`

Comment: I have added isset condition please check my answer now

Comment: it will give the result if that contains data. otherwise it will be skipped

Comment: i already seen that, now am getting `"message": "Undefined variable $offerLetters",
    "exception": "ErrorException",`

Comment: just set a default value for $offerLetter variable `$offerLetters = 0;` or null that suites you

Comment: thanks for your assistance, but i did try that and it give 0 as the result or null

Answer (score 0):

do you need to use the second parameter of json_decode ? For remember, used if it's an associative array

```php
$client=Client::where('id',$client)->firstOrFail();
$arr = json_decode($client->attributes);
```

What return gettype() ? Array ?

Comment: this is giving the response of the whole attributes and we want to access the  offer_letter_variables in the attributes

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @maazin , the solution was to use  json_decode $client->attributes and then use foreach like so

```
$clientAttributes = json_decode($client->attributes);

foreach ($clientAttributes->offer_letter_variables as $variable){
  $offer_letters_variables->put(
    $variable,
    $request->{$variable} ?? 'not set'
  );
}

$attr = collect(['offer_letter_variables' => $offer_letters_variables]);
```